# What software and hardware can you use to write math and take notes?

Tags: math-software

I'm trying to basically replace paper. I want to be able to write things and draw things out as easily as I can on paper. I bought the [Wacom Intuos tablet](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EN27ULS) on Amazon but ended up returning because it didn't feel very natural to me. I think I need something with a display as far as the hardware goes. I'm still not so sure about what software to use though. I think something like CorelDRAW or Adobe Sketchbook would be adequate but I haven't tried them with a tablet with a display. I'm open to more suggestions.

Comment: I asked a very similar question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197218/tool-for-converting-maths-writing-to-latex). However, the focus is on $\TeX$. Is that what you are after? (Otherwise, you need to be more clear!)

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few of the math grad students around here use iPads and love it.  I'm pretty sure they have built-in apps for taking notes. They're highly portable and have internet capabilities too--pretty much the perfect thing to bring to class.